# How to add to an array within an object

Tags: javascript

I have this object and I'm trying to convert it.

```
names = {
  animals: ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
  flowers: ['Rose', 'Daisy']
}
```

I want to convert it into something like this

```
newObject = {
  type: ['animals', 'flowers']
  subtype: ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Snake', 'Rose', 'Daisy']
}
```

I wrote the following function but for some reason it's not populating correctly.

```
const newObject = {};

Object.keys(names).map(type => {
  newObject['types'] = [...newObject['types'], type];
      names[type].map(subtype => {
        newObject['subtypes'] = [...newObject['subtypes'], subtype];
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `.map()` callback should return what you want each element to turn into, so the callback behaves somewhat like a transformation function.
However, for a case like this, you don't need to use `.map()` and can just extract the keys and values from the object. As your values are arrays, you can use [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to merge the array of arrays into the one larger array of values for your `subtype` key:

```js
const names = {
  animals: ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
  flowers: ['Rose', 'Daisy']
}

const type = Object.keys(names);
const subtype = Object.values(names).flat();

const newObject = {type, subtype};
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newObject = {
  type: ['animals', 'flowers']
  subtype: [...names.animals, ...names.flowers] 
}
```

Comment: This implementation is not very flexible as you have to hard code values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build a new object:

```js
const names = {
  animals: ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
  flowers: ['Rose', 'Daisy']
};

const res = Object.entries(names)
                  .reduce(
                    ({type, subtype}, [key, values]) => ({
                      type: type.concat(key),
                      subtype: subtype.concat(values)
                    }),
                    { type: [], subtype: [] } // Starting value
                  );

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Global solution for any keys and values

> use `Object.keys` and `Object.values` with `array.reduce()` :)

```js
const names = {
   animals: ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
   flowers: ['Rose', 'Daisy']
}

const newObject = {
   type: Object.keys(names),
   subtype: Object.values(names).reduce((acc, item)=> [...acc, ...item],[])
}

console.log(newObject);
```